# Trouble using Bootstrap's display property d-none

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display a block of my code on medium screens and upper only, and display another block of code on small and extra small screens only using Bootstrap. I used Bootstrap's display properties, and I have a trouble with d-none on the first line. I used [Bootstrap doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/), but couldn't find where was my mistake.

Here is my code :

```
      <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center d-none d-md-block">
        <form class="form-inline d-flex justify-content-center md-form form-sm mt-0 search-desktop">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm ml-3 w-100" type="text" placeholder="Recherche..." aria-label="Search">
        </form>
      </div>
      <nav class="mobile-nav col-4 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center d-md-none">
        <svg width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-list" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 11.5A.5.5 0 0 1 3 11h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4A.5.5 0 0 1 3 7h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4A.5.5 0 0 1 3 3h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
        </svg>
      </nav>
```

The second block of code is working well, it's displaying on small and extra small screens only. But the first block of code is always displaying, even if I use d-none only (without d-md-block).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace **d-md-flex** with **d-flex** and remove **d-md-block**.

```html
      <div class="col-4 d-md-flex justify-content-end align-items-center d-none">
        <form class="form-inline d-flex justify-content-center md-form form-sm mt-0 search-desktop">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm ml-3 w-100" type="text" placeholder="Recherche..." aria-label="Search">
        </form>
      </div>
```